# What is the way for having a list through rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I am a bit new to rxjava. I am trying to have a list on rxjava by iterating on the result. I tried operator like toList() but does not work out. The following is working fine. However, I wonder if there is a better way from reactive perspective?

```
db.loadData().map(new Func1<RealmResults<Data>, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> call(RealmResults<Data> Datas) {
            List<String> companies = new ArrayList<String>(5);
            for (Company company : Datas.get(0).getCompanies()) {
                companies.add(company.getName());
            }
            return companies;
        }
    }).subscribe(new Action1<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<String> strings) {
            showCompanyDialog(strings);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like that (pseudoCode as I don't know the object types you have):

```
db.loadData()
    .map(new Func1<RealmResults<Data>, List<Company>>() ) {
        public List<Company> call(RealmResults<Data> Datas) {
            return Datas.get(0).getCompanies();
        } 
    }).flatMap(new Func1<List<Company>, Observable<Company>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Company> call(List<Company> companies) {
            return Observable.from(companies);
        }
    }.map(new Func1<Company, String>() {
        public Stringcall(Company company) {
            return company.getName();
        }
    }).toList();
```

That means:

1. Get results from database
2. Get companies from RealmResult
3. Split into companies
4. Get name of each company
5. Concatenate all results to a `List<String>`

Comment: I know it's not part of the question, but maybe you guys would find Retrolambda useful. It's a backport for java 8 lambdas for java 5, 6 and 7. https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: Retrolambda has one minus. It does not automatically add correct types. So, when You are learning RxJava, you will get crazy when trying to write something. You need to know at first the input and output parameters of ie. Func1 or Func2 interfaces.
I tried retrolambda, but did not decide to use from that case. Now, when I know RxJava better, sure will try it in the next project.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the java 8, but it's the only way that this makes sense:

```
db.loadData()
  .flatMapIterable(results -> results)
  .flatMapIterable(data -> data.getCompanies())
  .toList()
  .subscribe(this::showCompanyDialog);
```

Isn't it much more concise?

Comment: could you please expand it to the normal version without retrolambada?

Answer (score 0):

to get "flatten" company name list(in blocking way),

```
List<String> names = db.loadData()
    .map(datas -> datas.get(0).getCompanies())
    .flatMap(companies -> Observable.from(companies))
    .map(company -> company.getName())
    .toList()
    .toBlocking()
    .single()
```